# Sublime Text 3 — обзор папок при помощи FTP плагина

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Установил плагин для управления файлами через FTP, но вот очень неудобно выбирать папку или файл через эту консольку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли реализовать, чтобы все файлы и папки считывались так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В sublime text не знаю такое возможно или нет, но можно установить отличную программу для работу с кодом NetBeans( https://netbeans.org/ ). Я лично им пользуюсь и очень доволен. P.S. Там такое возможно. P.P.S. Гит тоже им поддерживается.

Comment: Да я пользуюсь тоже им малость, но мне как то не удобно там, хотя там функционал куда интересней

Answer (score 1):

Package Control выдаёт много вариантов плагинов, содержащих в своём имени `FTP`, — неплохо было бы указать, какой именно установили. Но в целом везде будет выводиться консоль под верхним меню.

На самом деле, если вникнуть, это **очень** удобно, поскольку поддерживается т. н. [fuzzy поиск](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147856/):

[image: Fuzzy поиск]

«Одна из самых разрекламированных функций редактора — нечёткий поиск. Он позволяет найти `modules/gallery/view/gallery/page.jade`, вбив лишь `gapaja`. Сказать, что это экономит время, — всё равно, что ничего не сказать. В 99% случаев я открываю файлы или нахожу нужную мне функцию по вот таким вот обрывкам, напоминающим какой-то восточноазиатский диалект. А, к примеру, вбив `gapaja@gallery_list`, мы попадём не в начало файла, а сразу к mixin-у `gallery_list`. Из коробки доступны:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> — поиск по файлам проекта,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> — поиск по функциям (template-ам в `XSLT`, селекторам в `CSS`/`SCSS` и т. д.),
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> — поиск по меню (а туда попадают, в том числе, и новые функции из плагинов, т. е. не обязательно запоминать горячие клавиши для редко используемых возможностей),
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> — поиск по словам. Например, вбив `dbr`, можно найти, где же вы забыли убрать служебный debugger в js-файле,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> — номер строки (не fuzzy-поиск).»

---

Если же Вам не нравится визуальное оформление верхних консолей, <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Browse Packages...</kbd> → <kbd>User</kbd> → создаёте файл **Default.Sublime-theme**, если он ещё не создан, → между `[]` вписываете:

```
// Рамка верхних консолей
    {
        "class": "overlay_control",
        "layer1.tint": [205, 133, 63],
        "layer1.opacity": 1.0,
    },
// Рамка, обрамляющая форму ввода текста в верхних консолях и панелях Find and Replace 
    {
        "class": "text_line_control",
        "layer1.tint": [255, 218, 185],
        "layer1.opacity": 1,
        },
// Размеры ячеек выпадающего меню верхних консолей
    {
        "class": "quick_panel",
        "row_padding": [10, 10],
    },
// Текст в выпадающем меню верхних консолей, 3 класса
    {
        "class": "quick_panel_label",
        "fg": [255, 228, 225, 255],
        "match_fg": [240, 128, 128, 255],
        "bg": [188, 143, 143, 255],
        "selected_fg": [255, 0, 0, 255],
        "selected_match_fg": [255, 240, 245, 255],
        "selected_bg": [173, 216, 230, 255],
    },
    {
        "class": "quick_panel_score_label",
        "fg": [255, 165, 0, 255],
        "bg": [176, 224, 130, 255],
        "selected_fg": [0, 206, 209, 255],
        "selected_bg": [64, 64, 64, 255],
    },
    {
        "class": "quick_panel_path_label",
        "fg": [255, 255, 0, 255],
        "match_fg": [255, 139, 0, 255],
        "bg": [255, 0, 0, 255],
        "selected_fg": [224, 255, 255, 255],
        "selected_match_fg": [255, 0, 255, 255],
        "selected_bg": [255, 255, 0, 255],
    },
```

Результат:

[image: Цвета Fuzzy поиска]

В квадратных скобках цвета в [RGB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB) или [RGBA](http://cuprum.name/page/cvetovaya-model-rgba). Изменяйте их, если не устраивают предложенные мной.

Спасибо.